# Function inside if condition returns true, but does not go into body

Tags: c++, if-statement, gdb

I have two functions:

```
bool f() const
int g() const
```

The if-statement in question lies within a while loop, as follows:

```
while(/*get next element*/){
  if ( f() || g() == 5 ) continue;
  // Do some stuff...
}
```

`gdb` tells me that `f()` returns `TRUE`; however, the `continue` isn't being executed. The program goes further in the loop body to "do some stuff".

What is the problem here? Is `gdb` lying to me?

**Solution:** The previous revision of my code did not include the call to `f()` in the if-statement. I forgot to recompile, so the source had me believing the call was there, but it wasn't. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19989652/1566525

Comment: It is too localized and likely will not help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **gdb:** Source file is more recent that executable

Thought I recompiled, but apparently did not. Wish that warning stood out a bit more.

My last revision did not have the call to `f()` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Is you `if` statement inside any loop?

**From cppreference:**

> Causes the remaining portion of the enclosing for, range-for, while or
>   do-while loop body skipped. Used when it is otherwise awkward to
>   ignore the remaining portion of the loop using conditional statements.